# set inside createUser callback returns PERMISSION_DENIED with security rules

Tags: firebase

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is buggy behavior:

I set up the following security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "test": {
      "$location": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    },
    "test1": {
      "$location": {
        ".read": "$location === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$location === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then do createUser and in the callback I issue:

```
testRef.child('test/bla/bla/bla').set('val1',
```

and

```
testRef.child('test1/' + authData.uid + '/bla/bla/bla').set('val1',
```

However test1 fails !
In the console I see PERMISSION_DENIED

You can see a demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvajnxya/

If instead I do createUser then unauth then authWithPassword and then the set then both test and test1 work - this proves to me that the security rules are fine.

You can test that in the fiddle by remarking setvals(authData); and unremarking unauthAuthwithpassSet(authData);

I would appreciate feedback on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written is working as expected. [`Firebase.createUser()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html) only creates a user and *does not authenticate the user*.

Comment: Because the first set requires no authentication. Anyone can write to `/test/$location`. If you want to require auth, you need to use `auth != null` instead of `true`.